# Not enough input arguments, when inputs are specified

Tags: matlab

This feels like a really dumb question because the error message is really straight forward, so I took a while to create as simple of a complete example as I could. It seems like when a constructor is called in a constructor ( I think I first noticed in a normal method not a constructor) and the objects are being put into an array in reverse order then matlab will give a `not enough input arguments error` for example:

```
classdef practice
    methods
        function self = practice(b)
            b
            if b>1
                for i = 2:-1:1
                    s(i) = practice(b-i);
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

called as

`practice(4)`

gives

```
b =

     4


b =

     2


b =

     0

Error using practice (line 4)
Not enough input arguments.

Error in practice (line 7)
                    s(i) = practice(b-i);

Error in practice (line 7)
                    s(i) = practice(b-i);
```

This case is odd because it only fails when getting to where b <= 1, but my real code doesn't fail like this. Any ideas on what exactly is going wrong and how I can fix it?

Comment: Actually the constructor can't have an instance as the first method, but isn't static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is on the first iteration, when `b = 4`, you set `s(i) = practice(b-i)` and `i = 2`. This will initialize `s` to an array of `practice` of `length` 2, but since you initialize the second element first, the first element will get initialized to a default `practice`, where input `b` is undefined.

If you change the indices over `i` iterates to `i = 1:2` this should fix the problem.

**Edit:**

For example, try clearing your workspace and then doing:

`s(2) = practice(0)`

This will attempt to assign `practice(0)` to `s(2)` and then `s(1)` will get assigned a default initialized `practice`, in which case `b` is not defined. This will replicate the problem you're having. The solution is to assign to `s(1)` first, and then `s(2)` next.